# Queue-based implementation recursive function

Tags: c++, function, queue

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

void operateQueue1(queue<int> q) {
    while (!q.empty()) {
        std::cout << q.front() << " ";
        q.pop();
    }
}

void operateQueue2(queue<int>& q) {
    if (q.empty()) {
        return;
    }
    int data = q.front();
    q.pop();
    operateQueue2(q);
    q.push(data);
}

int main() {
    std::queue<int> myQueue;
    myQueue.push(20);
    myQueue.push(25);
    myQueue.pop();
    myQueue.push(myQueue.back());
    myQueue.push(myQueue.front());
    myQueue.push(myQueue.front() + myQueue.back());

    operateQueue1(myQueue);
    operateQueue2(myQueue);
    operateQueue1(myQueue);

    return 0;
}
```

So from what I understand from this code, the queue state before operating on operateQueue2 is 25, 25, 25, 50. In the above code for the function `void operateQueue2`, there is a `q.pop()` where from what I see from the output it does not actually remove any element out of the queue. Therefore, I am asking what is the purpose of the `q.pop()` in `operateQueue2`

Comment: *I can paste the explanation in the comments if need be.* -- [Do not paste comments from an AI engine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1).

Comment: After looking at a video from geeksofgeeks, I have understood how the 'q.pop()' works but it says that it will return if 'q.empty()' but if after adding the first value 50 into the q why would it still return?

Comment: C++ isn't a language you will understand by trial and error and asking ChatGPT (ChatGPT really doesn't have a clue about good C++).

Comment: @EdwinC. Recommending "geekforgeeks" is not recommended. That's a very low quality site too

Comment: Better sources to learn C++ from are a [recent book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) (make sure it is up-to-date and not teaching you "C"). Or you can use  [learncpp.com](https://learncpp.com/). Also make sure to check [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) to explore what C++ has to offer (containers/algorithms). 
And finally refer to the [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) to learn how C++  is intended to be used.

Comment: *After looking at a video from geeksofgeeks* -- Run the code locally in a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems).  Not only will you learn the flow of the program, you learn how to use a debugger and thus avoid poor sites like "geekforgeeks" and needing to go to ChatGPT to answer logic flow questions.

Comment: `void operateQueue1(queue<int> q)` -- That `q` is passed by value, thus it is local to the function.   It is *not* `myQueue`, only a copy of it.  When `operateQueue1` returns, all of those changes done to `q` go away.

Comment: Oof, "I asked ChatGPT and Geeksforgeeks for programming help" is about akin to "I needed help landing a plane, so I called my guitarist friend and a pile of bricks for help".I recommend not using either of those resources in the future. ChatGPT can be *very* lightly useful as a quicker Google if you know the tooling, but it's not an educational tool. And Geeksforgeeks is just SEO clickbait with no real value.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, try not to `using namespace std;`. There is a wonderful question full of informative [linked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) to tell you the reasons.

Now, you see, the `q.pop()` does remove elements as the function is called, but if you observe, this recursive function uses a new integer to save what you remove before you remove it. Recursively, this function is like a loop that saves all of the front values of your queue in order, but then see that after you hit `q.empty()`, the function returns to the previous call and continues with `q.push(data)`. However, the value of the integer `data` is the last element before you did the final `q.pop()`, so actually, you push your previous last element into the front. After that, your functions continually end and then `q.push(data)` for each integer in your queue in reverse order. In the end, this entire code is just a way to reverse the contents of `myQueue`, printing the queue before and after. As such, according to your question, the purpose of the `q.pop()` is to make room for the next integer in line to be saved and later pushed back in in reverse order.

State of the Queue Before Operate Functions:

```
25 25 25 50
```

State of the Queue After Operate Functions:

```
50 25 25 25
```

If you run this code, you can see it more clearly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
void operateQueue1(std::queue <int> q) {
    while (!q.empty()) {
        std::cout << q.front() << ' ';
        q.pop();
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    return;
}
void operateQueue2 (std::queue <int> &q) {
    if (q.empty()) { return; }
    int data = q.front();
    q.pop();
    operateQueue2(q);
    q.push(data);
}
int main() {
    std::queue<int> myQueue;
    myQueue.push(20);
    myQueue.push(25);
    myQueue.pop();
    myQueue.push(myQueue.back());
    myQueue.push(myQueue.front());
    myQueue.push(myQueue.front() + myQueue.back());
    std::cout << "Before reverse:\n";
    operateQueue1(myQueue);
    operateQueue2(myQueue);
    std::cout << "After reverse:\n";
    operateQueue1(myQueue);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm explaining this as simple as possible, operateQueue2 simply flips the queue.

```
void operateQueue2(queue<int>& q) {
    if (q.empty()) {
        return;
    }
    int data = q.front();
    q.pop();
    operateQueue2(q);
    q.push(data); 
};
```

**Explanation**:

First detail, q is a reference to the original queue (queue& is a [reference type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference)) that means any changes affect the original object.

Let's manually work this through, q = [25,25,50]

and we call operateQueue(q) for the first time.

**First iteration**:

```
int data = q.front()
q.pop();
```

We get the first element of the queue **data_1 = 25** (I'm calling it data_1 to signify the iteration the variable is in) and remove it with pop().
After that, 'operateQueue2' gets called again this time the queue **q = [25,50]**

**2nd Iteration**:
We take the first element again and remove it (**data_2 = 25; q=[50]**)

**3rd Iteration**:
Do it once more (**data_3 = 50; q=[]**).

Now the for forth Iteration we give it q which now is empty making the function return and continue where we left off in the 3rd iteration, meaning data_3 = 50 and q=[] (because we emptied), and

```
q.push(data);
```

will fill the queue again this time with data (because we returned to the 3rd iteration data is data_3), thus **q=[50]** and now the function ended and we return to the caller which is the 2nd iteration that also fills the queue with 'data' (data_2),

now **q=[50,25]**.

The function ends again and we return for the last time to the caller, the first iteration that fills the queue with data_1 and now

**q=[50,25,25]** The reverse of what it started as.